# How can I launch a .jar program from Ant?

Tags: java, ant, websphere

I need to launch a java program from Ant. I have this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project name="ANT_PDA">
<target name="run">
        <java jar="C:\workspace\program\mainDESA.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>
```

but doesnt work. How can I execute the .jar? thanks

Comment: Does that jar has `Main-Class` attribute in its manifest file? And please elaborate *doesn't work* as a general practice.

Comment: I created a java console program, and exported the build to a folder, then I put the above code, to the path of the .jar